# Why I have this problems trying to insert a conditional value of an input tag inside a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have some problem setting conditionally a value inside an input field of a JSP page.

So I have wrote the following line inside my page:

```
<input disabled id="ulterioreSaldo" class="form-control rightAlligned" style="width:100px;" <c:if test="${progetto.impAltSal == null}">value='<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="&euro;" type="currency" value="0" /></c:if> <c:if test="${progetto.impAltSal != null}">value='<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="&euro;" type="currency" value="${progetto.impAltSal}" />'</c:if> />
```

This line show a monetary amount so to do it I am using the **fmt** tag library to format the value and show the related currency symbol (it works).

As you can see I am trying to insert a condition for the value of this input tag.

If the value of the **progetto.impAltSal** is **null** the value have to be **0** so the output have to be **€ 0,00**.

If the value of the **progetto.impAltSal** is not **null**, this value have to be used as value of this input field, so the oytput will be something like **€ 15,37**

My problem is that doing in this way (considering the case in which **progetto.impAltSal** is **null**) the obtained output is: **€ 0,00 />**

It seems that include in the value also the **/>** that close the  tag, or something like it.

I have tried to change it but it can't work.

What am I missing? How can I correctly implement this feature inside my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo are missing a ' at the end of :

```
value='<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="&euro;" type="currency" value="0" />
```